# Spring ROO 2.0 & STS Java Version

Tags: spring-roo

Spring Roo 2.0 documentation shows 2 different recommended Java Versions.  https://docs.spring.io/spring-roo/docs/current/reference/html/#getting-started-requirements shows Java 7 as recommended and https://docs.spring.io/spring-roo/docs/current/reference/html/#getting-started-install-roo recommends Java 8.  I have tried both versions and I receive errors with Java 8 on both Mac High Siera and Windows 10.

[This is the error in Mac OSX when using Java 8:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AUzjD.png)

STS 4.02 will not install ROO (both nightly build/release build).  When I attempt to install ROO with STS 4.02 I get`Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: Spring IDE Roo Support 3.9.6.201809180658-RELEASE (org.springframework.ide.eclipse.roo.feature.feature.group 3.9.6.201809180658-RELEASE)
  Missing requirement: AspectJ 1.7.3.20130613144500-a (org.aspectj.ajde 1.7.3.20130613144500-a) requires 'osgi.bundle; org.eclipse.core.runtime.compatibility 0.0.0' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: AspectJ Compiler 1.7.3.20130613144500-a (org.aspectj.feature.group 1.7.3.20130613144500-a)
    To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; org.aspectj.ajde [1.7.3.20130613144500-a,1.7.3.20130613144500-a]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: AspectJ Development Tools 2.2.3.e43x-RELEASE-20130627-0800 (org.eclipse.ajdt.feature.group 2.2.3.e43x-RELEASE-20130627-0800)
    To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; org.aspectj.feature.group [1.7.3.20130613144500-a,1.7.3.20130613144500-a]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Spring IDE Roo Support 3.9.6.201809180658-RELEASE (org.springframework.ide.eclipse.roo.feature.feature.group 3.9.6.201809180658-RELEASE)
    To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; org.eclipse.ajdt.feature.group 2.0.1`

STS 3.96 and 4.02 will only run on Java 8, as indicated when you attempt to start STS with Java 8.

Therefore it appears ROO requires Java 7 and STS requires Java 8 at a minimum.

Has anyone encountered this?  Is there a way to get ROO 2.0 running on Windows 10 or Mac High Sierra in coordination with STS 4.0, both running on Java 8?

Comment: Just ran into the same problem on Linux.  Installing STS 3.9.7...